# Notepad ++ and regex. Returning string

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have the log file below.  I need to return the line directly below [Jon.Test]  I need to export this line to a separate document.

This is the statement I have so far.  It returns extra lines that are not needed.

```html
(\ Memory usage for process \[Jon.Test].*)(VM Size)
```

```html
2015-03-24 21:02:11,799 [6152 process; 1 thread] INFO  - Memory usage for process [Jon.Test]
2015-03-24 21:02:11,799 [6152 process; 1 thread] INFO  - &#9;Mem Usage:       537276 KB
2015-03-24 21:02:11,814 [6152 process; 1 thread] INFO  - &#9;VM Size:         553452 KB
2015-03-24 21:02:11,814 [6152 process; 1 thread] INFO  - &#9;Non-Paged Pool:  181.8164 KB
2015-03-24 21:02:11,799 [6152 process; 1 thread] INFO  - Memory usage for process [Jon.Test]
2015-03-24 21:02:11,799 [6152 process; 1 thread] INFO  - &#9;Mem Usage:       535376 KB
2015-03-24 21:02:11,814 [6152 process; 1 thread] INFO  - &#9;VM Size:         553452 KB
2015-03-24 21:02:11,799 [6152 process; 1 thread] INFO  - Memory usage for process [Jon.Test]
2015-03-24 21:02:11,799 [6152 process; 1 thread] INFO  - &#9;Mem Usage:       533576 KB
2015-03-24 21:02:11,814 [6152 process; 1 thread] INFO  - &#9;VM Size:         553452 KB
2015-03-24 21:02:11,814 [6152 process; 1 thread] INFO  - &#9;Non-Paged Pool:  181.8164 KB
2015-03-24 21:02:11,799 [6152 process; 1 thread] INFO  - Memory usage for process [Jon.Test]
2015-03-24 21:02:11,799 [6152 process; 1 thread] INFO  - &#9;Mem Usage:       577376 KB
2015-03-24 21:02:11,814 [6152 process; 1 thread] INFO  - &#9;VM Size:         553452 KB
2015-03-24 21:02:11,814 [6152 process; 1 thread] INFO  - &#9;Non-Paged Pool:  181.8164 KB
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Without fully looking at the log file, the first thing I'd try is to change the `*` to `+` to make it non-greedy and see what that does. If it doesn't fix it, and someone else doesn't beat me to it, I'll take a second look.

The `*` matches as many characters as possible (ie, greedy). The `+` matches only as many as necessary to make the match, (ie non-greedy).

Edit: so I took the log file over to a regex tester website. [google'd for regex calculator](http://www.infobyip.com/regularexpressioncalculator.php)

This is what I came up with:

```
\[Jon\.Test\](\s+.+)
```

Which returns:

```
[Jon.Test] 2015-03-24 21:02:11,799 [6152 process; 1 thread] INFO - Mem Usage: 537276 KB
[Jon.Test] 2015-03-24 21:02:11,799 [6152 process; 1 thread] INFO - Mem Usage: 535376 KB
[Jon.Test] 2015-03-24 21:02:11,799 [6152 process; 1 thread] INFO - Mem Usage: 533576 KB
```

Etc. Hope that helps.

Edit: also, if you want more explanation of the regex, there's helpful info at the bottom of the linked page. Also, if you wanted more lines, add `{2}` to the end, etc...

Comment: It still returns everything from the first [Jon.Test] to the last (VM Size)  Thank you for the comment its appreciated.

Comment: @JonGould: I'm happy to help. Please consider accepting my answer by clicking the green check box to let the StackOverflow community know you no longer need our help with this quesrion. :)